Add Connection Errors
MSSQL Extension Version: v1.19.1
VSCode Version: 1.70.2 (Universal)
OS Version: macOS 14.4.1 (23E224)
After downloading SQL Server v1.19.1, I ran into the same initial error messages as this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/17383.
Namely, when opening up the command palette, and inputting "MS SQL: Add Connection", I got the following error:

Command 'MS SQL: Add Connection' resulted in an error (command 'mssql.addObjectExplorer' not found)

However, upon checking the Extension Host and Command Palette, I was unable to replicate the errors they found. In addition, I was unable to implement their fix, because '%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-mssql.mssql-1.19.1' had no corresponding directory 'sqltoolsservice'.
I've tried closing and re-opening VSCode, redownloading the extension, and deleting all of the included extension files as in this post: command 'extension.addObjectExplorer' not found when using VS Code mssql extension. None of these had any noticable change to the problem.
How should I resolve this issue? Is there any more information I can provide?

ms-mssql.mssql extension v1.19.1 was released back on 2023-06-05. Is there a particular reason you haven't updated to the current version, v1.22.1?

%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-mssql.mssql-1.19.1 is a Windows path. Since you're on macOS have you tried looking in ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-mssql.mssql-1.19.1' instead?

Thanks AlwaysLearning, didn't realize that the MSSQL version wasn't current. Found out that the VSCode version wasn't current either when I checked why, and found another bug that I just resolved. Seems like that also resolved the issue!

The MSSQL Extension was not updated to the current version (v1.22.1). This is because the VSCode version had also not been updated. Updating VSCode (automatically or manually) did not work because of an error with updating to macOS 14. To resolve this issue VSCode suggested removing itself from the Downloads folder and making sure it was properly installed in Applications. This allowed me to update VSCode, which then came with the current version of the MSSQL Extension that worked as intended.
